# "String or unicode input unrecognized as WKT EWKT, and HEXEWKB"

Tags: python, django, geodjango, django-fixtures

I am trying to load a dumped geodjango fixture into postgis.  The fixture loads perfectly into other computers with the same setup, but on my setup I get:

```
ValueError: Problem installing fixture 'C:\....json': String or unicode input unrecognized as WKT EWKT, and HEXEWKB.
```

(I am quite sure this is a configuration/environment related problem.)

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be that your environment is missing the `python-gdal` library. The dependency error is being hidden by an [`except` statement](https://github.com/djangonauts/django-rest-framework-gis/blob/625a36b176d12878c654333a81a5004836ee33db/rest_framework_gis/fields.py#L44) that has been [raised as an issue](https://github.com/djangonauts/django-rest-framework-gis/issues/91).